# What modules of Helmet should I use in my REST Api

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, helmet.js

Question:

Which Helmet modules should be used  for a rest API?

Background:

I am building a Node/Express REST Api and keep seeing Helmet pop up as a security middleware I should be using. Looking at Helmet's documentation is looks like some of the modules (Content Security Policy, Cross Domain, ect) are only applicable to front end apps. Which modules should be used in Helmet for a rest API?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

tl;dr: the following might be useful for an API, though you could set more to be safe:

- [`helmet.expectCt`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/expect-ct/), which sets the `Expect-CT` header, is useful if the consumer of your API knows how to handle certificate transparency
- [`helmet.frameguard`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/frameguard/), which sets the `X-Frame-Options` header, is useful if your API responses are ever put into an `iframe` or similar. (I have run into this personally.)
- [`helmet.hsts`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/), which sets the `Strict-Transport-Security` header, helps keep users on HTTPS
- [`helmet.noSniff`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/dont-sniff-mimetype), which sets the `X-Content-Type-Options` header, is useful in browsers that might try to auto-detect your API response's type and do something unexpected. (I have run into this personally.)
- [`helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/crossdomain/), which sets the `X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies` header, might be useful to protect your site against strange requests from Adobe products like Flash

---

Author of Helmet here.

I'd say there are two reasons to use Helmet (or the HTTP headers it sets) with an API:

1. Some of the headers are useful in non-browser use cases, like a REST API.
2. In case your response is ever loaded in a browser. For example, if a hacker puts it in an `<iframe>` and causes something unexpected to happen. (Old browsers sometimes have problems here, causing vulnerabilities.) You could also do it to future-proof your API in case it *is* ever loaded in the browser, even if it isn't today.

Helmet is just a collection of 13 smaller middlewares. Most of those set a single HTTP response header, and most of those headers are only useful in browsers. Some, however, are occasionally useful for APIs (REST or otherwise).

Let's enumerate them:

- [`helmet.contentSecurityPolicy`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/csp/), which sets the `Content-Security-Policy` header, is probably not useful
- [`helmet.dnsPrefetchControl`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/dns-prefetch-control/), which sets the `X-DNS-Prefetch-Control` header, is probably not useful
- [`helmet.expectCt`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/expect-ct/), which sets the `Expect-CT` header, **might be useful** if the consumer of your API knows how to handle certificate transparency
- [`helmet.featurePolicy`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/feature-policy/), which sets the `Feature-Policy` header, is probably not useful
- [`helmet.frameguard`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/frameguard/), which sets the `X-Frame-Options` header, **might be useful** in case your API responses are ever put into an `iframe` or similar. (I have run into this personally.)
- [`helmet.hidePoweredBy`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hide-powered-by), which removes the `X-Powered-By` header, is probably not useful (it's not even that useful in browsers!)
- [`helmet.hsts`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/), which sets the `Strict-Transport-Security` header, **might be useful** to keep users on HTTPS
- [`helmet.ieNoOpen`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/ienoopen/), which  sets the `X-Download-Options` header, is probably not useful
- [`helmet.noCache`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/nocache/) is going to be removed in future Helmet versions and isn't super useful for security anyway, so it's probably not useful
- [`helmet.noSniff`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/dont-sniff-mimetype), which sets the `X-Content-Type-Options` header, **might be useful** in browsers that might try to auto-detect your API response's type and do something unexpected. (I have run into this personally.)
- [`helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/crossdomain/), which sets the `X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies` header, **might be useful** to protect your site against strange requests from Adobe products like Flash
- [`helmet.referrerPolicy`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/referrer-policy/), which sets the `Referrer-Policy` header, is probably not useful
- [`helmet.xssFilter`](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/xss-filter/), which sets the `X-XSS-Protection` header, is probably not useful

In summary: a few of them might be useful—might be worth setting a few of these headers just to be safe.

Comment: Why would case filter not be useful? It appears from the other two comments that it is used for that.

Comment: `xssFilter` is probably not useful because (1) API consumers shouldn't be executing JavaScript at all (2) it's not a thorough protection against XSS attacks, even in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The big reason people use Helmet inside their restful api is to avoid (XSS) and script injection . All you have to do is this. Remember it is just an express middleware.

```
const helmet = require("helmet");
app.use(helmet())
```

Answer (score 0):

Helmet is an Express.js middleware. And is used to avoid script injection. When you initialize your app, use Helmet like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
```

Hope this helped :)